# How to create a file with python scrip in nodejs child process?

Tags: python, node.js, child-process

I'm using a python 2.7 script to create a file, which I want to open later from a node.js server. When I run the script from cmd it creates a file, but when the node.js server runs the python script it's not working.

Node.js code:

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

var process = spawn('python', ["./assets/python_scripts/test.py"]);

process.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    res.json(data.toString());
});
```

Python code:

```
file = open("HelloWorld.txt","w+")
file.write('Hello World')
file.close()
print('File created')
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Where did you look for the file? It probably was created in the working directory of the node.js server, not where you executed the Python file directly.

Comment: It might be a syntactic error, `var spawn = require("child_process")` look here : https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options